# Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?: Heroku/Django

Tags: python, django, heroku, heroku-postgres

I've been struggling over this for days now and none of the numerous threads I've come across have worked for me.

I have a Postgresql DB with postgis extention that I access with pgadmin4 for my Django app.

I semi-successfully deployed my application to Heroku, except anything that needs data from the psql DB does not work, I get the error mentioned in the title.

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    },
    
     'geospatial': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'geospatial',
        'USER': '****',
        'PASSWORD': '****',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

error:

```
OperationalError at /facility/
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://lessmedtxt.herokuapp.com/facility/
Django Version: 3.1.5
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

adding the below code to my settings.py does nothing either:

```
import dj_database_url
geodbtest = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['geospatial'].update(geodbtest)
DATABASES['geospatial']['ENGINE'] = 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis'

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

I've run `heroku run python manage.py migrate` but it says I have no migrations to apply.

Please help me, I've spent days over trying to deploy this thing.

Edit: Just checked my Heroku dashboard and the DB has [0 connections.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkEzb.png)

Comment: Is there a Postgres server on your Heroku machine?  You're connecting to `localhost`, so it must be the same machine.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, they're on the same machine. The app works fine locally. I just don't know how to get heroku to work with my progresql server. Is that an issue though?

Comment: The fact that you say "locally" makes me suspicious.  Are you saying it works on machine "A", but not on machine "B"?  Have you configured machine B's Postgres to accept network connections?  Have you created your username there?  Are you sure it's on port 5432?

Comment: You can't use `localhost` here as Heroku won't spin up a PostgreSQL instance on the same dyno. Use the Heroku dashboard to see the correct hostname for your database.